# Div width not resizing for dynamic content

Tags: html, css, jquery-masonry

I am having trouble with the width of a div not resizing when it's dynamic content is loaded.

[image]

As you can see in this screenshot, that the first few divs do not get the width of it's dynamically loaded child images.  But as you can see, the later divs that are loaded after the server have time to render the child images DO get the child width.

The site is based on Masonry.  I have been trying to solve this problem with a masonry method called:

```
$('.masonry-container').masonry('reloadItems')
```

but it is not working.

I have also tried:

```
window.location.reload()
```

but all that does is reload the page.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You should post some code snippets or point to a "live" site.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is a css or html issue. I think this has to do with the scripting side of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If your layout has images, you probably need to use imagesLoaded.
>   http://masonry.desandro.com/faq.html

Answer (score 0):

Try looking in some Developer tools, like Chrome's and inspect the "half-loaded" image, you should usually see why it's not wrapping the content.